# Creality CR-10S Pro V2 Auto Bed Leveling probe sticks

Tags: troubleshooting, bltouch, creality-cr-10

My CR-10 is only a couple of months old. It came factory fitted with auto bed leveling.

Recently, the bed leveling probe has stuck in the withdrawn position whilst it is measuring prior to a print. Whilst stuck in this position the red light flashes. I am able to temporarily resolve the problem by gently pulling the probe down, but then have to start the measuring process all over again.

This problem is occurring more often and if I don't sit through the lengthy measuring process and restart if necessary, the printer will carry on printing in 'mid-air'.

Comment: Have you found a permanent solution to this? If so, please post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having moved the probe up and down gently to ensure it wasn't catching, I restarted the machine and have not been troubled since.